# Fabric js: Increase font size instead of just scaling when resize with mouse

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am working on fabric js application & I need to increase/decrease  the font size when we resize the font with mouse

my tried code

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#text-font-size').keyup(function() {
        var val = $(this).val();
        if (isNaN(val)) {
            alert('please enter number');
            $(this).val('');
        }
        var activeObject = canvas.getActiveObject();
        activeObject.fontSize = val;
        canvas.renderAll();
    });
    $('#add-text-btn').click(function() {
        if ($('#text-font-size').val()) {
            var txtfontsize = $('#text-font-size').val();
        } else {
            var txtfontsize = 40;
        }
        var message = $('#add-text-value').val();
        //var txtfontfamily = $('#font-family').val();
        var new_text = new fabric.IText(message, {
            left: 100,
            top: 100,
            fontSize: txtfontsize,
            //fontFamily: txtfontfamily,
            fill: '#000'
        });
        canvas.add(new_text);
        canvas.setActiveObject(new_text);
    });

    canvas.on('object:selected', function(options) {
        if (options.target) {
            $("textarea#add-text-value").val(options.target.text);
            $("#text-font-size").val(options.target.fontSize);
        }
    });

    canvas.on('object:scaling', function(options) {
        if (options.target) {
            $("textarea#add-text-value").val(options.target.text);
            $("#text-font-size").val(options.target.fontSize);
        }
    });

    canvas.on('object:modified', function(options) {
        if (options.target) {
            $("textarea#add-text-value").val(options.target.text);
            $("#text-font-size").val(options.target.fontSize);
        }
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.5.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="add-text-btn">Add text</button><br><br>
<textarea rows="7" id="add-text-value">Your Text Here</textarea>
<br>
<input id="text-font-size" type="text" class="form-control">
<canvas id='canvas' width="500" height="400" style="border:#000 1px solid;"></canvas>
```

but this this just rescale the text not increase/decrease the font size but i have to resize the font size like in [this](http://www.signomatic.com/signomatic/banner)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The idea is using the canvas.on("object:modified") event to reset the scaling to 1 and increase fontSize to fit the new size.

fabric.Object.lockUniScaling is a suggested addition.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#text-font-size').keyup(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if (isNaN(val)) {
      alert('please enter number');
      $(this).val('');
    }
    var activeObject = canvas.getActiveObject();
    activeObject.fontSize = val;
    canvas.renderAll();
  });
  $('#add-text-btn').click(function() {
    if ($('#text-font-size').val()) {
      var txtfontsize = $('#text-font-size').val();
    } else {
      var txtfontsize = 40;
    }
    var message = $('#add-text-value').val();
    //var txtfontfamily = $('#font-family').val();
    var new_text = new fabric.IText(message, {
      left: 100,
      top: 100,
      fontSize: txtfontsize,
      lockUniScaling: true,
      //fontFamily: txtfontfamily,
      fill: '#000'
    });
    canvas.add(new_text);
    canvas.setActiveObject(new_text);
  });

  canvas.on('object:selected', function(options) {
    if (options.target) {
      $("textarea#add-text-value").val(options.target.text);
      $("#text-font-size").val(options.target.fontSize);
    }
  });

  canvas.on('object:scaling', function(event) {
    if (event.target) {
      $("textarea#add-text-value").val(event.target.text);
      $("#text-font-size").val((event.target.fontSize * event.target.scaleX).toFixed(0));
    }
  });

  canvas.on('object:modified', function(event) {
    if (event.target) {
      event.target.fontSize *= event.target.scaleX;
      event.target.fontSize = event.target.fontSize.toFixed(0);
      event.target.scaleX = 1;
      event.target.scaleY = 1;
      event.target._clearCache();
      $("textarea#add-text-value").val(event.target.text);
      $("#text-font-size").val(event.target.fontSize);
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.5.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="add-text-btn">Add text</button>
<br>
<br>
<textarea rows="7" id="add-text-value">Your Text Here</textarea>
<br>
<input id="text-font-size" placeholder="fontsize" type="number" class="form-control">
<canvas id='canvas' width="500" height="400" style="border:#000 1px solid;"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for help, now this works on actual font size(include decimals) , can we font size to round figures here i tries with this event.target.fontSize *= Math.round(event.target.scaleX); but not working  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1jkh7ooo/)

Comment: you cannot round the scaling, otherwise you will jump from 40 to 80 to 120... ( scaling 1,2,3). You have to round the fontSize after the multiplication. see updated answer.

Comment: Also you will notice some problem with object dimension that will of course jump but also you should tell fabricjs that you need new coordiante system for the object. with setCoords();

Comment: ,thanks but can you make one more favour , now it change font size value in input  text  when scale is completed, i want to change value regularly when scaling the font like provided  like this [link](http://www.signomatic.com/signomatic/banner)

Comment: just insert the calculation in canvas.on("object:scaling")

Comment: can you explain this in brief which type of calculation

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi Could you please explain what does the code 'event.target._clearCache()' do?

Comment: _clearCache clear the two caching arrays for lineWidths and lineHeights ( we do not recalculate them every time in fabricjs) i do not know why i force the call since a change in fontsize trigger the cleaning automatically.

Comment: How can i get current active Text object font size?

Comment: this Solution not working on group scaling, do you have any solution for calculate new font size when user try to scale whole group of text.

Answer (score 0):

While perhaps not the best approach (I'm new to Fabric), this is working for me with version 4.3.0:

```
canvas.on('text:changed', function (e) {
  console.log('Text:', e.target.text, e.target.text.length)
  let objectSelection = canvas.getActiveObject()
  switch (e.target.text.length) {
    case 10:
      console.log(`Text is ${e.target.text.length} characters in length.`)
      objectSelection.set('fontSize', 100)
      break
    case 15:
      console.log(`Text is ${e.target.text.length} characters in length.`)
      objectSelection.set('fontSize', 85)
      break
    case 25:
      console.log(`Text is ${e.target.text.length} characters in length.`)
      objectSelection.set('fontSize', 60)
      break
  }
})
canvas.on('text:editing:exited', function (e) {
  console.log('Text edited!')
})
```

I took [inspiration from another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18480453/630530), which does the job.